# I have a problem with <a> Tag when using block content in django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

First of all I am new to django. I have a project with 4 pages and pages root is look like below:

```
myProject/create/
myProject/create/project
myProject/create/activity
myProject/create/discipline
```

I made a base.html file in templates/myapp/base.html and add a sidebar there. I added links of all pages in  in base.html to access to other pages. then with the {% extend %} formula I extended sidebar from this page to see a it on other pages too and its working. So my structure of project is look like this:

```
myProject
├── create
│   ├── project
│   ├── activity
│   ├── discipline
```

when I am in "create" page and I click on project page, I goes on that page and its working. but the problem is when I am in sub pages like "project" page and I click on other pages (ex: activity) it goes to:
MyProject/Create/**project**/activity
which is not true. what should I do to be able to go to myProject/create/activity and not to MyProject/Create/project/activity from sub pages ?

Comment: Please show your template `base.html` and urls.py file

Comment: You should use a leading slash, so `<a href="/myProject/create/project">`

Answer (score 1):

You should work with a leading slash (`/`), otherwise you are defining a [*query-relative url* [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-url-20120524/#resolve-a-string-as-a-query-relative-url). By using a leading slash, it means it will keep the hostname, and replaces the old path with the new path.

You thus link with:

```
<a href="/myProject/create/project">…</a>
```

That being said, it is often better to resolve the URLs with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).